# how to display an image from web service

Tags: c#

I am building my first app in windows phone 7. I need to show data from web service along with an image. I am able to show the data but not able to show the image.

My xaml code is:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">


        <ListBox Name="listBox1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Button.Content>
                            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="80" Width="400">
                                <!--<ScrollViewer Height="80">-->
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="80">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image_Path}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

The .cs code is:

```
 public class Newss
    {
        public string News_Title { get; set; }
        public string News_Description { get; set; }
        public string Date_Start { get; set; }

    }

   public News()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KejriwalService.aapSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
        client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
        client.getarvindNewsAsync();
    }

    void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result.ToString();
        List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);

       foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))

       {
            Newss data = new Newss();
            data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;
            data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
            listData.Add(data);
        }

        listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;

    }
}
```

Xml String:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <UserDetails>
    <id>11</id>
    <News_Title>Disciplinary Action against Vinod Binny</News_Title>
    <News_Description>The Aam Aadmi Party formed a disciplinary committee, on 19-Jan-2013, headed by Pankaj Gupta to look into the matter of Vinod Kumar Binny. The other members of the committee included Ashish Talwar, Illyas Azmi, Yogendra Yadav and Gopal Rai.

This disciplinary committee has decided to expel Vinod Kumar Binny and terminate his primary membership from the party, for publicly making false statements against the party and its leadership, thereby bringing disrepute to the party. A letter to the same end has been issued to Vinod Kumar Binny.</News_Description>
    <Date_Start>2014-01-29</Date_Start>
    <image_path>news.png</image_path>
```

Can anyone help me in displaying the images for each field.

The image path is an http url

```
http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/news.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i guess right your Image_Path is a http url . so you need to BitmapImage to bind as a ImageSource. may this will help you.

```
 public class Newss
        {
            public string News_Title { get; set; }
            public string News_Description { get; set; }
            public string Date_Start { get; set; }
            **//Edits**
            public string image_path {get;set}
            public BitmapImage ImageBind{get;set;}
        }
     foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
           {
                Newss data = new Newss();
                data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;
                data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
                **//Edits**
                data.image_path = location.Element("Image_Path").Value;
                data.ImageBind = new BitmapImage(new Uri( @"http://political-leader.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal/images/uploaded/"+data.image_path, UriKind.Absolute)
                listData.Add(data);
            }

**Your xaml changes**

    <Image Source="{Binding ImageBind }" />
```

Comment: Where to give the url

Comment: @user3156298 : Url is coming in `data.Image_Path `...

try the above code as it is....

Comment: Its not working. No error. I am getting the same result i.e., only the text

Comment: @user3156298 could you share xml string.

Comment: Please see the xml string. In my list box i only want to show the image, date_start, news_title. When any one title is clicked the description for that should be shown in a new page. Moreover the image is not coming.

Comment: @user3156298 i saw your xaml. but i want to see your xml string which you get from webservice. as i want to know in which format you get image whether its a url only or Base64String.

Comment: @user3156298 i made changes in my ans. Please give a look.